# How can I change the Python that my Django project is using?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have 2 versions installed in my server. I used virtualenv to install Python 2.7.

I am using WSGI to deploy my project.

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/my_project/wsgi.py
```

My http.conf is like that.

python -V gives

Python 2.7.3

But in my projects Debug window, it says Django is using 2.6.8. Where am I wrong?

UPDATE: Here is my wsgi file

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/html')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Python Version: 2.6.8
Python Path:
['/home/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_transmeta-0.6.7-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.13-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv-1.7.2-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info',
 '/var/www/html']

In my error_log of httpd:

[Tue Jul 10 20:51:29 2012] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.6.7', found '2.6.8'.
[Tue Jul 10 20:51:29 2012] [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Tue Jul 10 20:51:29 2012] [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib64/python26.zip:/usr/lib64/python2.6/:/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2:/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk:/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old:/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload'.

Comment: What debug window? Are you using an IDE? If so, you need to tell us which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod_wsgi module must be compiled for the specific Python major/minor version you want to use. You cannnot use WSGIPythonHome to force a mod_wsgi compiled against Python 2.6 to use a Python virtual environment constructed using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to configure the application's wsgi script to use a specific virtualenv.

If that is the case check out modwsgi's docs:
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

I'd try to TLDR it for you, but its very well written at that link and I wouldn't be able to do it justice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) you can control which version of python is being used directly in the configuration file.

Comment: You could do what Buildout does -- just put the python that you want to use at the top of your WSGI script.  Like so:

#!/somepath/python/bin/python2.7

Comment: Did you restart your web server?

Comment: Sorry -- I guess I can't help.